# Visual Studio Code - working with two sub-windows but making them not affect one another?

Tags: windows-10, code, translation, visual-studio-code, split-window

Visual Studio Code (VSCODE to all you coming here from search engines) allows splitting the current working window into two windows:

[image]

When I type text in one, it appears in the other.

I desire that such automatic copy-pasting of thext in Window 1 to Window 2 won't occur.

I need Window 2 to have its own different text that I myself will write or paste.

I need this because I translate code from one language to another.

Is there a way to do so in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "Split Editor Right" Button opens a second Group with the same document active.
It only makes sense that your writing is copied over as it is the same document.

To get what you want, you only need to create two different files and open each in one Group/Tab.

[image: A short gif video showing the described behavior]

Comment: After splitting I went to the first window, l clicked File > New File (`CTRL+N) and than just closed the first one and it was even faster creation; maybe you'd like to edit per this comment. Thank you !